# Attempt to create a variadic C++ input function

Tags: c++

Recently I've been doing some CP stuff and grew bored of using `cin` in C++.
So I thought I could at least create a cleaner input function.

So I'm stuck here.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void read() {}

template <typename T, typename... Type>
void read(T var1, Type... var2) {
    cin >> var1;
    read(var2...);
}

int main () {
    int x, y;
    read(x, y);
    cout << x << " " << y;
}
```

If I enter some input like this :

```
2 3
```

It's supposed to print out something like this

```
2 3
```

Instead, I always receive some stuff that starts with 1 and then some random number

```
1 203354149
```

So, my question is, does a variadic input function exist in C++ and if it does, how can I write it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is your arguments to `read` are passed by value, so the variables in `main` are never modified. You need to take the arguments by reference instead. You can also use fold-expressions to make `read` much cleaner

```
template <typename... Ts>
void read(Ts & ...vs) 
{
    (std::cin >> ... >> vs);
}
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bGs9v43c6)

---

Also, please get out of the habit of using the following code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>  // bad
using namespace std;      // bad
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take your arguments by reference.

```
template <typename T, typename... Type>
void read(T& var1, Type&... var2) { // <-- Note the reference here
    cin >> var1;
    read(var2...);
}
```

Comment: Uh, sir, I mean this code did succeed in taking the first number, but not the second

Comment: `Type... var2` left taking copies.

Comment: 10 12 -> 10 1 in my case